# Subclassing python's dict, override of __setitem__ doesn't retain new value

Tags: python, subclass, dictionary

I'm subclassing dict, but ran into a problem with **setitem** where one assignment works, but another assignment does not. I've boiled it down to the following basic problem:

```
class CustomDict(dict):
 def __setitem__(self, key, value):
  super(CustomDict, self).__setitem__(key, value)
```

Test 1 fails:

```
data = {"message":"foo"}
CustomDict(data)["message"] = "bar"
print CustomDict(data) # Expected "{'message': 'bar'}". Actual is "{'message': 'foo'}".
print data # Expected "{'message': 'bar'}". Actual is "{'message': 'foo'}".
```

Test 2 succeeds:

```
data = CustomDict({"message":"foo"})
data["message"] = "bar"
print CustomDict(data) # Expected "{'message': 'bar'}". Actual matches expected.
print data # Expected "{'message': 'bar'}". Actual matches expected.
```

I looked online but couldn't tell whether the subclass constructor copies the dictionary so operations are performed on a different instance of the dictionary. Any advice?

Answer (score 10):

You are constructing new instances of CustomDict on each line.  `CustomDict(data)` makes a new instance, which copies `data`.

Try this:

```
cd = CustomData({"message":"foo"})
cd["message"] = "bar"
print cd # prints "{'message': 'bar'}".
```

Comment: Thanks, Ned. Is it a deep copy, and any suggestions on where to look in the python code to find the __init__ for dict?

Comment: It is not a deep copy.  The code for dict is quite involved, 2500 lines of C. If you want to read it, it's in Objcets/dictobject.c in a Python source distribution.